# Python Class Utilizing Turtle object not working on Windows, Works on Linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, turtle-graphics

The code below executes fine on a Linux machine but doesn't work on Windows. I'm not sure why.

I've tried the suggested answer of adding in `d.getscreen().mainloop()` as well, but to no avail. The code has been tested on two different windows machines.

```
import turtle
import time

class Display(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.screen = self.getscreen()
        self.hideturtle()
        self.speed(0)
        self.screen.tracer(0)
        self.screen.colormode(255)

    def koch(self, order, size):
        # self.forward(size)
        # self.left(order)
        if order == 0:
            self.forward(size)
            return
        else:
            for angle in [60, -120, 60, 0]:
                self.koch(order - 1, size / 3)
                self.left(angle)

    def clearscreen(self):
        self.clear()

    def moveTurtle(self, x=50, y=50):
        self.goto(self.xcor() - x, self.ycor() + 50)

def main():
    d = Display()

    prompt = True
    while prompt:
        order = input("What order do you want your fractal? ")
        size = input("What size do you want your fractal? ")
        if order == '' or size == '':
            prompt = False
        else:
            d.koch(int(order), int(size))
        d.penup()
        d.moveTurtle()
        d.pendown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Looks like you have some indentation issues, but that might have been a copy and paste problem.

Comment: No syntax/runtime errors.  The only difference in execution is that when it's run on the University's Linux machine it draws on the turtle graphics windows.  It's the same editor and code synced through git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is the problem lies here:

```
self.screen.tracer(0)
```

You turned off the graphics and never turned them back on.  This needs to be followed at some point by either:

```
self.screen.tracer(1)
```

or:

```
self.screen.update()
```

or both.

For testing purposes, comment it out altogether.  Some operations cause an update to happen (e.g. `penup()`) but this may be implementation specific and what you're running up against.

My rework of your code to incorporate the above and some style changes:

```
from turtle import Turtle

class Display(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        Turtle.__init__(self, visible=False)
        self.screen = self.getscreen()
        self.speed('fastest')

    def koch(self, order, size):
        if order == 0:
            self.forward(size)
            return

        for angle in [60, -120, 60, 0]:
            self.koch(order - 1, size / 3)
            self.left(angle)

    def moveTurtle(self, x=50, y=50):
        self.goto(self.xcor() - x, self.ycor() + y)

def main():
    d = Display()

    prompt = True

    while prompt:
        order = input("What order do you want your fractal? ")

        if order == '':
            prompt = False
            continue

        size = input("What size do you want your fractal? ")

        if size == '':
            prompt = False
            continue

        d.screen.tracer(False)
        d.koch(int(order), int(size))
        d.screen.tracer(True)

        d.penup()
        d.moveTurtle()
        d.pendown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This did it! It was the screen.tracer() method.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are initializing your d variable in a function scope, and then trying to access it outside. So you need to either assign the variable in a global scope, or pass them as parameters to your function (or alternatively do it all under the your main function).

Also I noticed you are initializing your while loop before calling the main function. I see you aren't calling the Screen loop to do anything with the code once it's done.

If you suspect the issue is your Windows machine, try running the turtle demo and see if that opens up the turtle window. The command for that is:   python -m turtledemo

### Changes I would make (and tested in Windows 10, Ubuntu 16.04)

```
def main():
    d = Display()
    prompt = True
    while prompt:
        order = input("What order do you want your fractal? ")
        size = input("What size do you want your fractal? ")
        if order == '' or size == '':
            prompt = False
        else:
            d.koch(int(order), int(size))
        d.penup()
        d.moveTurtle()
        d.pendown()
    d.getscreen().mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The formatting in the above code does indeed look incorrect but that was my fault when I copy/pasted (first time posting here).  Unfortunately, I'm still not seeing the code execute as expected even with adding the only relevant suggested change of d.getscreen().mainloop().  I've tested on two different windows machines now and its the same.

Comment: Do you have more code that interacts with the Display object you are creating? This is the code I was testing with: https://repl.it/repls/ConstantWorrisomeOutcome  (It won't run in the browser because of lack of turtle support in their interpreter) Is the issue that the turtle window doesn't open at all for you?

Comment: It's only the code above.  The turtle window opens in both environments.  Interestingly, I'm unable to move the turtle window at all when it first opens in Windows but I can do so on Linux.  I've also tried both powershell and command prompt on Windows and two different windows machines now.

Comment: You won't be able to move the window until you are out of the prompt loop. That's fairly normal unless you use separate threads. Are these school computers? Out of curiosity, what python version are you running? (on the windows machine)

Comment: Python 3.6.4 (Windows) vs Python 3.5.2 (Linux).  I asked one of my TAs a similar problem and he said it's because in older versions of python the implementation of turtle graphics changed for the mainloop() method relating to screen updates so that's likely the difference.